# How to open bootstrap popover without button in Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, popover, ng2-bootstrap

How to check if popover is open in Angular 2?

HTML:

```
<template #jobParametersPopover>
 <div style="width: 100%;">
                                        Popover content
                                    </div>
                                </template>                                   

                                <div [container]="body" #popover="ngbPopover" placement="bottom" [ngbPopover]="jobParametersPopover" popoverTitle="Job Parameters" style="width: 100%" class="panel-draggable" 
                                *ngFor="let tcs of defaultSuiteFiles; let x = index">                      
                                    {{tcs.name}}    
                                </div>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild('popover') public popover: NgbPopover;
 //...
console.log(this.popover.isOpen()) //throws exception
```

Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isOpen' of undefined

Comment: you want to open popover or check whether the popover is opened or not, make the question clear

Comment: I want to check whether popover is opened.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify to ViewChild decorator what to read:

```
@ViewChild('popover', {read: 'NgbPopover'}) public popover: NgbPopover;
```